# How does one get the first key,value pair from F# Map without knowing the key?

Tags: dictionary, f#, key-value

How does one get the first `key,value pair` from F# [Map](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353880.aspx) without knowing the key?

I know that the Map type is used to get a corresponding value given a key, e.g. [find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340502.aspx).

I also know that one can convert the map to a list and use List.Head, e.g.

```
List.head (Map.toList map)
```

I would like to do this
1. without a key
2. without knowing the types of the key and value
3. without using a mutable
4. without iterating through the entire map
5. without doing a conversion that iterates through the entire map behind the seen, e.g. Map.toList, etc.

I am also aware that if one gets the first `key,value pair` it might not be of use because the map documentation does not note if using map in two different calls guarantees the same order.

If the code can not be written then an existing reference from a site such as MSDN explaining and showing why not would be accepted.

TLDR;

How I arrived at this problem was converting this function:

```
let findmin l = 
    List.foldBack
        (fun (_,pr1 as p1) (_,pr2 as p2) -> if pr1 <= pr2 then p1 else p2)
        (List.tail l) (List.head l)
```

which is based on list and is used to find the minimum value in the associative list of `string * int`.

An example list:

```
["+",10; "-",10; "*",20; "/",20]
```

The list is used for parsing binary operator expressions that have precedence where the string is the binary operator and the int is the precedence. Other functions are preformed on the data such that using F# map might be an advantage over list. I have not decided on a final solution but wanted to explore this problem with map while it was still in the forefront.

Currently I am using:

```
let findmin m =
    if Map.isEmpty m then 
        None
    else
        let result = 
            Map.foldBack 
                (fun key value (k,v) -> 
                    if value <= v then (key,value) 
                    else (k,v))
                m ("",1000)
        Some(result)
```

but here I had to hard code in the initial state `("",1000)` when what would be better is just using the first value in the map as the initial state and then passing the remainder of the map as the starting map as was done with the list:

```
(List.tail l) (List.head l)
```

Yes this is partitioning the map but that did not work e.g.,

```
let infixes = ["+",10; "-",10; "*",20; "/",20]
let infixMap = infixes |> Map.ofList
let mutable test = true
let fx k v : bool =
    if test then 
        printfn "first"
        test <- false
        true
    else 
        printfn "rest"
        false
let (first,rest) = Map.partition fx infixMap
```

which results in

```
val rest : Map<string,int> = map [("*", 20); ("+", 10); ("-", 10)]  
val first : Map<string,int> = map [("/", 20)]
```

which are two maps and not a key,value pair for first

```
("/",20)
```

### Notes about answers

For practical purposes with regards to the precedence parsing seeing the `+` operations before `-` in the final transformation is preferable so returning `+` before `-` is desirable. Thus this variation of the answer by [marklam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36719524/1243762)

```
let findmin (map : Map<_,_>) = map |> Seq.minBy (fun kvp -> kvp.Value)
```

achieves this and does this variation by [Tomas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36719634/1243762)

```
let findmin m = 
    Map.foldBack (fun k2 v2 st ->
        match st with
        | Some(k1, v1) when v1 < v2 -> st
        | _ -> Some(k2, v2)) m None
```

The use of `Seq.head` does return the first item in the `map` but one must be aware that the `map` is constructed with the keys sorted so while for my practical example I would like to start with the lowest value being `10` and since the items are sorted by `key` the first one returned is `("*",20)` with `*` being the first key because the keys are strings and sorted by such.

For me to practically use the answer by [marklam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36719524/1243762) I had to check for an empty list before calling and massage the output from a [KeyValuePair](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42(v=vs.110).aspx) into a tuple using `let (a,b) = kvp.Key,kvp.Value`

Comment: is Map always has a strict order?

Comment: @FoggyFinder I am confused on how to answer that. The pairs can be entered in unordered and can be ordered for use and the code modified for them being in order which is one avenue I am working on. But you are asking if `Map always has a strict order` and as I understand map, the order is irrelevant because the key is used to pick out one `key,value pair` regardless of order.

Comment: What leads you to believe that `Map.toSeq` iterates through the entire map?

Comment: @kvb Glad you asked. I thought that it did, but by the fact that it is you who is asking tells me I am probably wrong. :)  Is there any official documentation stating that it does not iterate thorough the entire map? I checked [`Map.toSeq`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353481.aspx) but saw nothing. [Map](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353880.aspx)  for `toSeq` does state `Views the collection as an enumerable sequence of pairs.` but that doesn't leave me in a state of firm belief one way or the other.

Comment: @GuyCoder - The documentation doesn't guarantee it (but what would the documentation say - "This doesn't eagerly iterate through the map and build a new data structure"?), but logically there's no need for it.  `Map<_,_>`s are already sorted and implement `seq<_>`, so it would be pretty weird for `toSeq` to have to do anything extreme.  You can look at the [implementation](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/map.fs#L717) to verify that it's just calling `Seq.map` on the map's existing `seq<_>` representation.

Comment: @kvb Thanks for the reference to the implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Map` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<_,_>>` so you can treat it as a `Seq`, like:

`let findmin (map : Map<_,_>) = map |> Seq.minBy (fun kvp -> kvp.Key)`

Comment: Given that `Map` stores its values in ascending order already, wouldn't `let findmin (map : Map<_,_>) = Seq.head map` be much simpler as well as avoid traversing the entire container (just to ignore all but the first element)?

Comment: If it's guaranteed that Map will always and forever return its IEnumerable as sorted on the key, then yes. If it's an implementation detail that's not documented then you'd at least want a unit test that would show whether that had changed.

Comment: The documentation says specifically "Keys are ordered by F# generic comparison", not that it needs to IMO – the type would be rather useless if they weren't!

Comment: If that's documented, then that would be fine. But generally, maps only really need to offer a value for a key. IIRC .net's Dictionary<_,_> class is unsorted when enumerating.

Comment: IT _is_ documented, the very first sentence in the `Map` documentation in fact. And `Dictionary` is a hash table, not a binary tree, so that is to be expected. ;-]

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't suggesting that you were wrong about it being documented, just making the point that if something appears to behave in some way, but it's not explicitly documented, then one should be cautious about building on top of that behaviour :-)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is an answer that fully satisfies all your requirements, but:

1. You can just access the first key-value pair using `m |> Seq.head`. This is lazy unlike converting the map to list. This does not *guarantee* that you always get the same first element, but realistically, the implementation will guarantee that (it might change in the next version though).
2. For finding the minimum, you do not actually need the guarantee that `Seq.head` returns the same element always. It just needs to give you some element.
3. You can use other `Seq`-based functons as @marklam mentioned in his answer.
4. You can also use `fold` with state of type `option<'K * 'V>`, which you can initialize with `None` and then you do not have to worry about finding the first element:

   ```
   m |> Map.fold (fun st k2 v2 ->
       match st with
       | Some(k1, v1) when v1 < v2 -> st
       | _ -> Some(k2, v2)) None
   ```

Comment: I didn't think about initializing with None. Will have to remember that one.

Comment: I really appreciated your detail answer and learned something of value from both answers. Since it was a toss up for which one to choose, I decided that I always feel better when I know that the OP would give me the accept but decided to give the points to others needing them more.

Comment: @GuyCoder - If your last sentence means that you accepted answer A but only upvoted answer B because its author "needed points more", there's no reason not to also upvote answer A. Points on StackOverflow are not a competition, and you should upvote good answers regardless of who wrote them, or whether some other author "deserves" points more. If I've misunderstood your last sentence and you did upvote the accepted answer as well as this one, then just ignore this comment, since you already did the right thing. :-)

Comment: @munn Thanks. Unless an answer given to a question of mine is horribly wrong I usually give it an upvote. So I gave each question and upvote after testing it with the code against the original test cases using NUnit. Then when I started to use the code, while the answer from Tomas was the basis of the code, because the original code took care of the empty condition I did not need to use the option type so used`Seq.head` and pulled apart the kvp. The answer from marklan helped in understanding the current code I am using, but I still might change the code.

Comment: @munn If I didn't use any knowledge of what was given in the answer by marklan then I would have given the accept vote to Tomas without any thought. Also kvb gave me some more insight in a comment, to bad you can't get points by getting votes on comments.

Comment: @munn So the takeaway for me on this is as kvb suggested is to look at the F# implementation source code when I don't see a clear cut answer in the MSDN documentation.

Answer (score 2):

It's even simpler than the other answers. `Map` internally uses an AVL balanced tree so the entries are already ordered by key. As mentioned by @marklam `Map` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<_,_>>` so:

```
let m = Map.empty.Add("Y", 2).Add("X", 1)
let (key, value) = m |> Seq.head
// will return ("X", 1)
```

It doesn't matter what order the elements were added to the map, `Seq.head` can operate on the map directly and return the key/value mapping for the min key.

Sometimes it's required to explicitly convert Map to Seq:

```
let m = Map.empty.Add("Y", 2).Add("X", 1)
let (key, value) = m |> Map.toSeq |> Seq.head
```

The error message I've seen for this case says "the type `'a * 'b` does not match the type `Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, int>`". It may also be possible add type annotations rather than `Map.toSeq`.